# Hide list content until icon clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i do not want that list icons display on top of the Google icon until it is clicked.

[image: i do not want that list icons on top of google icon when it is unclicked]

I have tried adding `display:none` to every element.

```js
(function(){
 var ul=$("#navs"),li=$("#navs li"),i=li.length,n=i-1,r=120;
 ul.click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
   for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
    li.eq(a).css({
     'transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
     '-webkit-transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
     'left':(r*Math.cos(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))),
     'top':(-r*Math.sin(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180)))
    });
   }
  }else{
   li.removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
})($);
```

```css
#navs {
  position: fixed;
  left:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-128.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  z-index: 1007;
}

#navs>li,
#navs:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

#navs>li {
  transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  -moz-transition: .6s;
}

#navs a {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navs">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Add opacity 0 in css and opacity 1 in script click function

```
#navs>li{
 opacity: 0;
 ...
}

 li.eq(a).css({
  ... 
  'opacity':1
 })
```

```js
(function(){
 var ul=$("#navs"),li=$("#navs li"),i=li.length,n=i-1,r=120;
 ul.click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){           
   for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
    li.eq(a).css({
     'transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
     '-webkit-transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
     'left':(r*Math.cos(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))),
     'top':(-r*Math.sin(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))),
                   'opacity':1
    });
   }
  }else{
   li.removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
})($);
```

```css
#navs {
  position: fixed;
  left:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-128.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  z-index: 1007;
}

#navs>li,
#navs:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

#navs>li {
  transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  -moz-transition: .6s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#navs a {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navs">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: It is working and in ideal condition the  list links and circle are not visible but it's links are active. so even though i am clicking the top right of google icon but it is clicking on the link of the list. so how is there any way not to only hide the circles but also disable them before clicking the google icon?

Comment: i sorted it out.
#navs a {
  ...
  display: none;
}

and

(function(){
 ...
         'display': "inline-block"
       });
   }
  }else{
   li.removeAttr('style');
      lia.removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
})($);

Answer (score 0):

Some how tried to hide the `li` initially. check the snippet. 
However you need to adjust the size of those `circles`

```js
(function(){
 var ul=$("#navs"),li=$("#navs li"),i=li.length,n=i-1,r=120;
 ul.click(function(){
        
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
   for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
    li.eq(a).css({
     'transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
     '-webkit-transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
     'left':(r*Math.cos(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))),
     'top':(-r*Math.sin(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))),
                    'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)'
    });
   }
  }else{
   li.removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
})($);
```

```css
#navs {
  position: fixed;
  left:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-128.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  z-index: 1007;
}

#navs>li,
#navs:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

#navs>li {
  transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  -moz-transition: .6s;
}

#navs a {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  /*background color removed from here and given to transition logic of js*/
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navs">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
```